# Distinct function on a list does not change the list

Tags: c#

Why is the distinct function not working? Every other function works when I use it this way (I really mean every other - Sort changes list, OrderBy does not; AddRange changes list, Concat does not - very confusing).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            List<string> infos = text.Split(" ").ToList();
            infos.Distinct();
            foreach (string info in infos)
            {
                Console.Write(info + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `Distinct()` is a method of `IEnumerable<T>`, not `List<T>`. It _returns_ the distinct sequence and doesn't filter in place. You probably want `infos = infos.Distinct().ToList();`. Or you could just do it all in one line: `var infos = text.Split(" ").Distinct().ToList();`.

Comment: Side note: oneliner `Console.Write(string.Join(" ", Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Distinct()));`

Comment: In other words, the "Distinct" function is immutable. It doesn't modify your original collection instead it returns you a new List of distinct elements.